# How to compare values between two rows with a condition

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have values in two rows and I need to compare the cells in each column except the ones where is one of the two cells (or both of them) blank and get a result of how many values in row 4 is greater than the ones in row 5.

It looks like this [image: Example]

The result in this case should be 3.

Is there any way how to do it only with one formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=ArrayFormula(SUM((4:4>5:5)*(4:4<>"")*(5:5<>"")))`

- `(A) * (B) * (C)` ... - and logic
- `(A) + (B) + (C)` ... - or logic

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a single formula to do this in.

I tried both `=sum(if((a1:g1)>(a2:g2);1;0))`, as well as `=total(foreach(if((a1:g1)>(a2:g2);1;0)))`

and they simply evaluated to zero.

As far as I know, it looks like you will have to use two formulae,

```
=if((a1>a2);1;0) through =if((g1>g2);1;0)
```

then

`sum(a3:g3)`, where `a3...g3` is the above if statements.

Comment: This is basically my old solution which I'm trying to simplify with one formula but I also can't find the way how to do it..